# $\gcd (f,g)$ is a non-trivial divisor of $f$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose that $\pi$ is an irreducibel polynomial and $\pi$ divides $f$ and $g$ where $0<\deg(g)<\deg(f)$. Why is $\gcd(f,g)$ then a non-trivial divisor in $f$ ? Maybe I should mention that $f,g\in\mathbb{F}_p[X]$.

Comment: What is the problem? That $\gcd(f,g)$ is a divisor of $f$ or that it is non-trivial?

Comment: That it is non trivial.

Comment: Ok, so I figured it out I think. I forgot that irreducible elemenst cannot be units by definition, and all constant polynomials are units, and it follows.

Comment: :-) You also need to use $\deg(g) < \deg(f)$: $f$ is also called a trivial divisor of $f$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** $\,\ \ \color{#0a0}{1 \mid} (f,g)\color{#c00}{\mid f}\ $ is a *nontrivial* factor iff neither divisibility reverses, which is true,

$\quad $ for $\ (f,g)\color{#0a0}{\mid 1}\ $ and $\,\pi\mid f,g\,\Rightarrow\,\pi\mid(f,g)\mid 1,\,$ contra $\ \pi\,$ prime,

$\quad\!$ and $\ \color{#c00}{f\mid }(f,g)\mid f,g\,\Rightarrow\, f\mid g,\ $ contra $\ \deg f > \deg g.$